# Shekhinah and death penalty

Tags: tanach

Shalom. Seeing the Shekhinah (probably the fire from where Gd speaks (Deuteronomy 4,12; 5,4) was liable to death according to Exodus 33,22? The Shekhinah is not G-d's face (panim), right?

Comment: Could you please edit to clarify what the question is? Right now, I see two statements terminated with question marks.

Answer (score -2):

First off, G-d does not have a face. Secondly, the shekhinah is not a distinct entity, separate from G-d. This anti-monotheistic view reflects the dangers of a polytheistic belief. Rather, we should understand the shekhinah figuratively, as a human feeling of the presence of G-d. To do otherwise borders on polytheism.

Comment: You didn't answer the question.

Comment: @robev What are your suggestions?

Comment: Address the question asked above

Comment: @robev unfortunately, the question was closed. I would, otherwise, rewrite my answer as you suggested. Thanks for the suggestion, though.